# JPA many to many self referencing relation with additional column

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I am working with JPA and use Hibernate as a provider to my SQL Server database.

I need a many-to-many self referencing relation that has an additional column or even more additional columns.

That is my current code. I am getting exceptions by Hibernate:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<Relation> relations;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "relPerson", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<Relation> inverseRelations;
}

@Entity
public class Relation implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "PersonID", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Person person;

  @Id
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "RelPersonId", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Person relPerson;
}
```

During runtime i get an exception from hibernate:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance
```

Is there any way to implement this a little bit more intelligent and nicely?? Without getting that exception.

Thanks,
ihrigb

Comment: Seems the error has nothing to do with the entities definitions, can you post the code the causes the exception to be thrown?

Comment: it is just a message from jsp

Comment: ok, but the exception is thrown in the application server layer, so can you show the context in which the entities are used, otherwise there is no way to help you.

Comment: You are mapping the `Relation` entity because of the extra attributes, I assume? Why are you mapping the inverseRelationships on the Person object?

Comment: i thought i need to map that??

Comment: Mapping the association table adds complexity to your domain model. You should only do it if its absolutely necessary. For example, if their are additional attributes on the association that need to be managed in your app. Is that the case here? I can't advise a solution without knowing.

Answer (score 0):

If an object not associated with a `Hibernate Session`, the object will be `Transient`.

An instance of `Relation` list may be `Transient`(Normally, There is no identifier value for that instance) when you save `Person`.

[Here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html) is better way to understand object state.

Comment: so how can i store those objects in the database?

Comment: `Transient` object cannot stored in the database.